# How to store data connection for later use by http request

Tags: rust, actix-web

I am building a backend application that uses a S3 bucket as main data provider and Rust's `actix-web` as web framework.
The bucket connection and the credentials are configured in my `main()` function, but I am struggling to pass the initialised bucket down to the actual request handler.

```
use actix_web::{get, web::Json, web::Path};
use actix_web::{middleware::Logger, App, HttpServer};
use awsregion::Region;
use dotenv::dotenv;
use s3::creds::Credentials;
use s3::Bucket;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct DataIdentifier {
    uuid: String,
}

#[get("/data/{uuid}")]
pub async fn get_data(data_identifier: Path<DataIdentifier>) -> Json<String> {
    let uuid = data_identifier.into_inner().uuid;
    Json(format!("Getting data for uuid {}!", uuid))
    // TODO retrieve data from s3 bucket
}

#[actix_web::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "debug");
    std::env::set_var("RUST_BACKTRACE", "1");
    env_logger::init();

    dotenv().ok();

    let api_port = std::env::var("API_PORT").expect("API_PORT must be set");
    let api_port_number: u16 = api_port.parse().expect("API_PORT must be a number");

    let s3_url = std::env::var("S3_URL").expect("S3_URL must be set");
    let s3_access_key = std::env::var("S3_ACCESS_KEY").expect("S3_ACCESS_KEY must be set");
    let s3_secret_key = std::env::var("S3_SECRET_KEY").expect("S3_SECRET_KEY must be set");

    let bucket = match Bucket::new(
        "logdata-bucket",
        Region::Custom {
            region: "eu-central-1".to_owned(),
            endpoint: s3_url.to_owned(),
        },
        match Credentials::new(Some(&s3_access_key), Some(&s3_secret_key), None, None, None) {
            Ok(credentials) => credentials,
            Err(e) => panic!("Failed to create credentials: {}", e),
        },
    ) {
        Ok(bucket) => bucket.with_path_style(),
        Err(e) => panic!("Failed to connect to bucket: {}", e),
    };

    // TODO: store bucket for later use by http request handler get_data

    HttpServer::new(move || {
        let logger = Logger::default();
        App::new().wrap(logger).service(get_data)
    })
    .bind(("127.0.0.1", api_port_number))?
    .run()
    .await
}
```

How would I pass the `bucket` to the `get_data` handler in this specific case?
What would be a general pattern for other data sources (e.g. DB connections, Caches, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `App::app_data` to share data between threads and retrieve the data in the requests:

```rs
App::new().wrap(logger)
    .app_data(actix_web::web::Data::new(bucket.clone())
    .service(get_data)
```

And then in your service

```rs
#[get("/data/{uuid}")]
pub async fn get_data(
    data_identifier: Path<DataIdentifier>,
    bucket: actix_web::web::Data<Bucket>, // retrieve share data in params with the Data type
) -> Json<String> {
    // use your bucket
}
```

Documentation about `actix_web::web::Data` https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/struct.Data.html